# How to add primary sort key to an already existing table in AWS dynamo db?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a pre-existing dynamo db table to which i want to add a primary sort key. All the items in the table contain the key which i want to delegate as the primary sort key.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't allow to add Sort key for the existing table.

It allows the following once the table is created.

> Modifies the provisioned throughput settings, global secondary
>   indexes, or DynamoDB Streams settings for a given table.

**Solution:-**

Please create a new table with redefined key attributes and copy the data from old table to new table.

Comment: DynamoDb allows you to create backup when deleting a table which is great.

Comment: @WitoldKaczurba you can't edit the backup however, so it will re-create the table with the same primary key and settings. To add a primary sort key you have to create a new table and use your own backup method other than the built in DynamoDB backup. You can use DataPipeline to backup and restore though with the old and new table.

Comment: What is the preferred way of copying data from old table?