# Is there a way I can replicate a DynamoDb table but add a sort key to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, amazon-data-pipeline

I have some DynamoDb tables populated by data and which don't have a sort key configured. [I read DDB doesn't let you add a sort key only at table creation and the only solution is to create a new table with the sort key configured](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46449583/12170770).The problem is I need to keep the data I have stored but add a sort key to these tables. As a quick mention I'm deploying my backend using [Serverless](https://www.serverless.com/) framework

I think one solution would be to use [AWS's Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html) service but I want to know if there are other options available. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My template for this resource looks like this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    userGroupsTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        TableName: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage, 'local'}-userGroups
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: 'userId'
            AttributeType: 'S'
          - AttributeName: 'organizationId'
            AttributeType: 'S'
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: 'userId'
            KeyType: 'HASH'
          - AttributeName: 'organizationId'
            KeyType: 'RANGE'
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: 'organizationIdIndex'
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: 'organizationId'
                KeyType: 'HASH'
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: 'ALL'
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 1
              WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        StreamSpecification:
          StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
```

Comment: Why not add a global secondary index (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html)?

Comment: @Guy Thanks for the sugestion but I need to add a SK to the table so I can store multiple items with the same PK. To give more details about the use-case, I have stored in these tables users and their role in an organization, but at the moment I cant have a single user admin in multiple organizations. Table fields are : userId (PK), organizationId (the one I need as SK) and role.

Comment: When you say replicate, do you have restrictions such as a huge number of items, you must keep the name of the table for other services? Might be easier to simply create a new table with the right schema and copy the items to it.

Comment: I deleted the old table manually and made a backup to S3 but when I'm trying to deploy the new table using serverless I encounter this [error](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/). The solution in the post doesn't work. Is there any other solution that you're aware of ?

Comment: this is a cloud formation issue and not a DyanoDB one. The creation of of the new table shouldn't be an issue. The main problem is probably how to load back the data that you backed up. I'm not sure that you can do that if the schema changed. It is probably easier to do it using something such as pipeline: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html

Comment: @Go_dot Having similar scenario. Could you pls post how you achieved this?